# Why is .then() undefined in redux promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I was trying to trigger an event after redux state have been updated so I ran a promise .then like this

```
logoutHandler = (event) => {
    console.log("logout Handler")
    event.preventDefault()
    window.FB.logout()
    this.props.LoggedIn(false).then(() => {
        this.props.history.replace('/signup');
    })
}
```

Notice this..

```
  this.props.LoggedIn(false).then(() => {
            this.props.history.replace('/signup');
        })
```

Where `.LoggedIn(false)` is a redux action.

This is throwing an error

> Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

This is my redux action

```
export const LoggedIn  = (isLoggedIn) => {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGGED_IN ,
      payload: isLoggedIn
    })
  }
}
```

**Question:** Can someone tell me what I would be doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you returning `promise` from `LoggedIn` action? Can you share the code of `LoggedIn` action?

Comment: How does your redux action look like

Comment: What is `LoggedIn`? Can you show its code?

Comment: @Prasun Updated my code with Redux action

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri please check my updated code

Comment: @Jerodev Please check my code with Redux action

Comment: You are not `return`ing the `dispatch(…)` result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Redux action isn't returning a Promise. Either you can create and return a new Promise

```
export const LoggedIn  = (isLoggedIn) => {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         dispatch({
             type: USER_LOGGED_IN ,
             payload: isLoggedIn
         })
         resolve();
    })
  }
}
```

or execute, history.replace from within the redux action itself

```
export const LoggedIn  = (isLoggedIn, history) => {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGGED_IN ,
      payload: isLoggedIn
    });
    history.replace('/signup');
  }
}


logoutHandler = (event) => {
    console.log("logout Handler")
    event.preventDefault()
    window.FB.logout()
    this.props.LoggedIn(false, this.props.history);
}
```

Comment: When I follow your first code snippet and do something like this `export const LoggedIn  = (isLoggedIn) => {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return new Promise((reject, resolve) => {
         dispatch({
             type: USER_LOGGED_IN ,
             payload: isLoggedIn
         })
         resolve();
    })
  }
}` it throws **Uncaught (in promise)** 
Also, Shubham can you please-please explain your answer about why I need to use promise in action

Comment: You are using a .then in your code and hence you need to return a Promise

Comment: @KuchBhi, I made a small mistake in my arguments order, please check the updated code

Comment: Doesn't `dispatch` already return a promise? If so, avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)! At least, use `Promise.resolve()` instead of `new Promise`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a Promise.

So instead do something like this:

```
logoutHandler = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  window.FB.logout()
  return this.props.LoggedIn(false).then(() => {
    this.props.history.replace('/signup');
    return Promise.resolve(); // Just return a resolved promise
  })
}
```

Comment: Do I need to include the promise as done by Shubham Khatri in my redux action as well? Also, Can you please explain that how we can resolve a promise we made in redux action here `this.props.LoggedIn(false).then(() => {
    this.props.history.replace('/signup');
    return Promise.resolve(); // Just return a resolved promise
  })`

Answer (score 1):

As per `redux-thunk` doc, you should return `Promise` from your inner function to use `.then` with the action.

> Any return value from the inner function will be available as the return value of dispatch itself. This is convenient for orchestrating an asynchronous control flow with thunk action creators dispatching each other and returning Promises to wait for each other’s completion:

Take a look at the document [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#composition).

The possible code has already shared by `Shubham Khatri`

Answer (score 0):

To implement anything related to state update, you can use react life cycle method componentDidUpdate(). whenever redux reducer returns a new state whole react applications gets re-rendered. After rendering, componentDidUpdate method is executed for every component.

> componentDidUpdate() is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (condition) {
     this.props.history.replace('/signup');
  }
}
```

*https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate*